# Does elasticsearch automatically update the lucene index on upgrade?

Tags: lucene, indexing, elasticsearch, upgrade

I want to upgrade elasticsearch from 0.90.1 to 1.1.0. It is unclear if elasticsearch will automatically reindex the data to the new Lucene version (used in 1.1.0).

Should I reindex my data or elasticsearch can do it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

It will upgrade your indexes automatically, but you should still back up your data.

More information on upgrading is here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html